# What is the iron-ajax equivalent of the Twilio curl call?

Tags: polymer, twilio

I'm trying to emulate the Twilio REST API call to send a SMS message. All my code samples here have been redacted.

Twilio provides this CURL call:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[[ sid ]]/Messages.json' \
--data-urlencode 'To=##########'  \
--data-urlencode 'From=+#########'  \
--data-urlencode 'Body=hi' \
-u [[ sid ]]:[AuthToken]
```

So I'm trying the following in my element:

```
<iron-ajax
auto
url="https://@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[[ sid ]]/Messages.json"
headers='{"Authorization": "Basic [[authHash]]"}'
handle-as="json"
content-type="application/json"
last-response="{{twilioResponse}}"
method="POST"></iron-ajax>
```

with the following JS to support it:

```
ready: function() {
  document.querySelector('iron-ajax').params = {
    "To": "+###########",
    "From": "+###########",
    "Body": "want to play"
  }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
{"code": 21603, "message": "A 'From' phone number is required.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21603", "status": 400}
```

**I have already tried just putting stringified JSON in the attributes of the element. That doesn't work!** But any other help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes I have had to change " to '. Maybe you can check console.log(xxx.params), does it look a proper JSON?

Comment: Can you see the network request being made in devtools? What parameters are being sent?

Comment: Figured it out, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was sending the body in the wrong format. Instead of JSON, it needed to be in a URI encoded string.

Thus, returning to my `iron-ajax` element:

```
body='{ "JSON": "format" }'
```

should become

```
body='JSON=format&From=###'
```